# Extract Only Date from DateTime Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, rethinkdb

I have an array which look like this and its working fine but I need to arrange them groupwise like DateWise:

```
[ 
  {
    name: 'Ali',
    startedAt: Wed Dec 28 2016 15:32:07 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
    userId: '0002'
  },
  {
    completedAt: Wed Dec 28 2016 12:51:47 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
    name: 'Aliy',
    startedAt: Wed Dec 28 2016 12:43:19 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
    userId: '212'
  },
  {
    name: 'Aliy',
    startedAt: Wed Dec 28 2016 12:43:06 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
    userId: '2121'
  }
]
```

I have a code which groups them on the basis of `startedAt` and it's working fine but the problem is that i want only date part like 28/12/2016.

The below code is used for grouping :

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, function(d) {
   return d.startedAt;
});
```

Comment: I suggest you to use https://momentjs.com

Comment: Note that your code at the end has a syntax error (extra `}`). Which is an excellent advertisement for why putting the closing `}` on the same line as the last statement of a block is an awkward and error-prone bracing style.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On any modern browser, you can use the first 10 characters of the return value of `toISOString`:

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(datas, function(d){
   return d.startedAt.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
});
```

The first ten characters are the year, then month, then date, zero-padded, e.g. `2017-01-17`.

Note that that will group them by the day in UTC, not local time.

Also note that `toISOString` was added in 2009 as part of ES5.

If you need to support obsolete browsers that don't have it, or you need to use local time, just build a string from the parts of the date you need, padding as necessary, using `getFullYear`/`getMonth`/`getDate` or `getUTCYear`/`getUTCMonth`/`getUTCDate` as needed.

Comment: thanks it works  but  can you  please  guide  me  through that how will i b able to show  it  in  my  Views  e.g  iam using  Marko as  view template  . Can  you tell me  that  how can i show it  DateWise

Comment: @DEO: Your best bet there is to give it a go, and if you run into a specific problem, post a question about that problem with your attempt and what's wrong with it.

Comment: You can also split on the ISOString `"T"`: `d.startedAt.toISOString().split("T")[0]`

Comment: `toISOString()` causes issues with timezones when the time is `00:00:00`. try `new Date('1984-12-23T00:00:00').toISOString()` when your timezone is not UTC.

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy - *"Note that that will group them by the day in UTC, not local time."* If the OP wants local time, they have to do what I describe later in the answer.